# Meaning of one seal and characters on my Chinese painting?

Tags: translation, characters, character-identification, seal

I have previously received great help here on discovering the meaning of characters and seals on a pair of Chinese paintings I own. I also own a third Chinese painting which I've always wondered what its seal and Chinese characters mean. The painting is a landscape painting and the seals and characters are situated on the upper-left corner (please see images below), thanks in advance for the help.
[image: thepainting]
The Chinese Landscape Painting.

[image: sealandcharacters]
Close-up of the paintings seal and characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

己亥 - The 己亥
year: The previous 己亥年 was 1995, further back was 1935

Read about [干支 - Sexagenary cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexagenary_cycle)

冬 - Winter

寫於 - expressed at

香港 - Hong Kong

程振 - Cheng Zhen (the author)

The seal also read "程振" in seal script

*寫 literally means "write" but @lilysirius pointed out 寫 here is short for 寫意 (express the feeling)*

Comment: I was taught that the 題款 on a painting, 寫 always means 寫意，a term of the technique/style of Chinese painting, not to write or a general 寫 in 寫生

Comment: in this case, 寫 should mean "created" or "expressed"

Comment: I don’t agree, it’s still 寫意. This is still one of the ways that I learned to do it myself. The verb to use is pretty fixed.

Comment: 寫意 literally means "express the feeling" and it would also include the meaning of  "to create"

Comment: 寫 is actually from calligraphy, to write something, either concrete or abstract. But then when 寫意 became a term, 寫 is used conventionally as a short hand for 寫意. As a 寫意畫 painter I wouldn’t think otherwise.

Comment: Side note: Google Translate: 寫意 = freehand (drawing), 寫 in 寫意 should be understood as 描寫 (describe)

Comment: Oh I see, you translate 寫 into express. That’s the cause of my previous confusion. To express seems to broad a verb while 寫意 is some specific term. But well, I don’t have better translations. The google translate also confuses me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140239/discussion-between-tang-ho-and-lilysirius).

Comment: I think 寫 means 簽(sign) here.

Comment: From the discussion so far, is it feasible to categorize 寫意 as a type of Chinese painting technique equivalent to the Western "Impressionist" style? Just a thought? So, we have "A Wintery Impression of Hong Kong"?

Comment: @TangHo Thank you for the translation. Do I understand you correctly that the characters says it's a Hong Kong winter landscape made between 1935-1995 and by an artist named Cheng Zhen. I can't seem to find much information about the artist when googling Cheng Zhen 程振, do you think that he is a less-known artist with not much recorded about his life?

Comment: It is "made either in  1935 or 1995"; I've never heard of the artist 程振 before. 1995 is more likely

Comment: @TangHo Ok, thanks again.